# Android Download Manager Path Appears to be invalid sometimes

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

Downloading through download Manager in android sometimes does not download and throw error path appears to be invalid and it corrects itself after sometime. This is very unusual behaviour of Android Download Manager .

I am downloading to external storage through  `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/app/" , my_app.apk)`

And when it does not download it throw this error in logcat:-

```
W/DownloadManager: Path appears to be invalid: /storage/emulated/0/app/my_app.apk
```

I think its because i am downloading in  custom directory in Android but i cannot use `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` in this i have to download only in custom directory .

Please let me know if some one has an answer .)

Comment: did you find an answer I am facing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that you have created a directory named "app" in which you want to store apks.
To create a directory:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
            File dir = new File(path.getAbsolutePath(), "/app/");  
            if (!dir.exists()) {    
                 dir.mkdir();  
            }
```

If you have already created such directory,then try this:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/app/" , "my_app.apk");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make ensure that the directory exist so you can use-

```
File root = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/app/");
  if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
     }
```

Then you can use this to set the download manager path

```
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/app/my_app.apk"));
```